# Unable to run compiled files - bash: ./a.out: Permission denied. (I've tried chmod)

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, permissions, chmod

First of all, there are many questions like this on AU. Still, none of them solved my problem.

I've compiled my C source using `cc test.c`, and it did generate `a.out` file.

However when I run it I get this error -

```
bash: ./a.out: Permission denied
```

My source is not in the home directory, it is on different FAT-32 partition, so I've mounted the drive in which the code is using the following command -

```
$ udisks --mount /dev/sda7 --mount-options umask=022
Mounted /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda7 at /media/48E9-FD53
$ cd /media/48E9-FD53/C
```

Then I compile my code using `cc`

I've also tried `gcc`. But still I get the same error.

Then I did - `chmod +x a.out`, still the same problem. Also with(`chmod 755 a.out`) and `chmod u+x a.out`.

I've also tried compiling and executing the program using `sudo`.

I've also tried - `sudo chown sannidhya:sannidhya a.out`.

I've tried every thing that I found on AU, still couldn't get it to work.

How can I run `.out` file (without moving it to home directory)?

**Note** - I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

But a **weird thing** here is, even after running `chmod +x a.out`, on running - `ls -l a.out`, I get-

```
-rw-r--r-- 1
```

also when I check the properties of `a.out`, under **Permissions** tab, there are only 2 modes available `Read only` and `Read and Write`.

Comment: Check you mount options with e.g. calling mount from command line without any further options. I assume the no exec bit is set

Comment: Run `strace a.out` and post output either here or on paste.ubuntu.com and provide link

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the binary off of the FAT32 filesystem and onto your native ext* filesystem, the binary should run, when given the right permissions (+x).

It is possible that a filesystem is mounted with no execution rights. So in addition to chmod, you will want to also check your filesystems' mount options.

Comment: I've mounted my partition using - `udisks --mount /dev/sda7 --mount-options umask=022`...

Comment: Have you tried copying the binary you compiled onto a different filesytem to attempt to run it?